# Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel: How to select sheets other than first sheet using selectSheetsByIndex?

Tags: laravel-excel

`Excel::selectSheets('GalleryPhotos')->load($path)->get();` causes an exception when the sheet "GalleryPhotos" has no rows. So, the alternative is to use `selectSheetsByIndex` instead of `selectSheets`. For example,

`Excel::selectSheetsByIndex(0)->load($path)->get();`

But I am encountering some strange issues.

When  I use `Excel::selectSheetsByIndex(0)->load($path)->get();`, it works fine. But when I change that to `Excel::selectSheetsByIndex(3)->load($path)->get();` (Please note that instead of selecting the first sheet, I am trying to select the fourth sheet.), it returns me an empty arrary. And any code after that to get data from the sheets return an empty array.

For example, `Excel::selectSheets('GradeReports')->load($path)->get();` returns an empty array, if I use `selectSheetsByIndex` for any sheet other than the first sheet.

I am using Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel v1.3.7 with Laravel 4.2.

Comment: Probably not relevant, but still - Excel may have hidden worksheets. They are not visible, but when selected by an index - it could return an empty worksheet thus the empty array.